How to Wire Hunter Ceiling Fan to Dual Slider Switch
I need some help with how to wire my Hunter ceiling fan/light so that they both work off of a dual slider switch.
Fan box
Dual gray wires - neutral
Dual blue wires - hot
Pink wire - light slider
Orange wire - fan slider
From fan
Black wire - fan
Blue wire - light
White wire - neutral
2 green ground wires from fan brackets.




Are you showing how the switch is wired now and saying it is not working?  Show a pic of the back of the switch, the front means nothing .  There should be a guide on the back of the switch.  You tell us what is in the "switch box" but the information is confusing. What is on the back of the switch?

You say you have dual gray neutrals and dual blue hots.  Presumably only one of the blue hots is the line hot since this type of double switch usually only takes one line hot.  Why would you have two? Perhaps the other blue hot would to send a line hot to the fan box to feed a wirelss remote control switch in the fan box if there was one (which there is not in your case). The dual neutrals would be the neutral with the line hot and neutral to the fan box. These fans use a shared neutral for light and fan whether you have a wireless remote or wall switches.

What country is this in?

US.  The way I have it hooked up now, the light works from the slider, but I cannot get the fan to.  The fan only works from the pull chain.

I swear I've seen this post before.

For US, that's an unusual combination of wire colors. Not wrong, necessarily, but unexpected. Someone's attempt to communicate that this was a switch loop, maybe?

This must be a condo or apartment building. It looks like commercial wiring.  The fan wiring is a mess.  From the fan I can see a black hot for the fan motor, a blue hot for the light, a white shared neutral and a green ground.  The switch has a black hot and a red and yellow switched hot.   The trick is finding what wires run from the switch box to the ceiling box.  I suspect there are wires in the ceiling box that don't go to the fan and should have been left alone.

The fan only works from the pull chain probably means you have the fan connected to line hot not switched hot or both. Do you have a non-contact voltage tester or other test equip? Find out if the fan slider switch is working by disconnecting the switched hot to the fan in the switch box. Is there variable switchable voltage on the switch lead for the fan? If so switch is working. While you have the fan switched hot disconnected, determine if the fan still works with the pull chain. If it does work then you have wired around the switch and must disconnect that.
